# Links not working on iOS with Fancybox installed (Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox

I've installed Fancybox to create image slideshows on my Wordpress website.

Here's an example of them working (on desktop): http://louisebparker.com/w-magazine/

You can click a thumbnail to start anywhere in the slideshow.

The problem is when I access the site on iOS, I can't click any links, even on pages without slideshows. I'm stuck on whatever page I land on without being able to navigate anywhere.

And when I remove Fancybox or install an older version, I'm able to click links again.

I'm using Wordpress and added scripts using these two lines:

```
wp_enqueue_style("fancybox",get_bloginfo("template_url")."/js/fancybox_v2/jquery.fancybox.css");

wp_enqueue_script("fancybox",get_bloginfo("template_url")."/js/fancybox_v2/jquery.fancybox.js");
```

I've also used this code to set Fancybox options/parameters:

```
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
            infobar: false,
            buttons: [
                "close"
            ],
            animationEffect: "fade",
            touch: {
            vertical: false
            },
        });
```

Any ideas?

I can't for the life of me figure this one out.

Comment: FYI, your code snippet is for fancybox v3, but looks like you have included files for v2. And your link does not work.

Comment: Thank you, the v2 is my own dumb naming, it's the latest version of Fancybox. I also updated the link, maybe it works now?

Comment: No, your link just redirects to https://www.shorturl.at/

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the link, here it is in full: http://louisebparker.com/w-magazine/

Comment: Could you fix `TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function` JS error on your page? Any JS error can potentially break further execution of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help. My version of Chrome isn't showing any errors in the Javascript console. Does your error say which file that occurs in?